# BSON library for Java/Scala that reads content right from disc

Tags: java, scala, serialization, bson

I'm looking for a BSON library for Java/Scala that can read really big (bigger than RAM) BSON file. It means that I don't want to read whole file at once, but only fragment-by-fragment. What is more I need only reading. Is there anything like this?

Comment: Are these mongodb files?

Comment: No, these are my own JSON-like objects that are simply to big to load at once

Comment: I guess you could use a scala mongodb util like [Reactive Mongo](http://reactivemongo.org/). It understands `BSON` and has streaming support. My guess is that it would be possible to stream from a file using that library.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [BSONSpec page](http://bsonspec.org/implementations.html)

Charly